# How to check if a number is prime? and if is not, how to increment the number until the function returns the next prime number?

Tags: javascript, primes

Thing is I do believe I already built the code that make it happen, the problem is that I'm trying to use it as an answer for the challenge at [jschallenger.com](https://www.jschallenger.com/javascript-basics/return-prime-number/challenge?id=5f082fa739c6fe165eb9f599), but the page do not accept my code as a valid answer.

Can anyone explain to me why the site does not accepts my code and how I can fix it? My code is right, right?

Here is my code:

```js
function checkPrime(number) {
  for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function myFunction(number) {
  if (checkPrime(number)) {
    return number;
  } else {
    while (checkPrime(number) === false) {
      number++;
    }
  }
  return number;
}

console.log(myFunction(38)); //the return should be 41
console.log(myFunction(7)); //the return should be 7
console.log(myFunction(115)); //the return should be 127
console.log(myFunction(2000)); //the return should be 2003
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the site does not accepts my code"? When your code runs here, it returns the values you expect.

Comment: They do not want you to make another global function. If you move `function checkPrime(number) { ...} ` inside of `myFunction` it will work

Comment: elaborating on "the site does not accepts my code": if you try running my code at jschallenger.com the code will not be a validated. The code is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the site only allows you to have the function and nothing else. Specifically in this situation: no separate functions. So if I put your `checkPrime` function inside `myFunction` it will pass successfully.

```js
function myFunction(number) {
  function checkPrime(number) {
    for (var i = 2; i < number; i++) {
      if (number % i === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  if (checkPrime(number)) {
    return number;
  } else {
    while (checkPrime(number) === false) {
      number++;
    }
  }
  return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(a) {
  for (let i = 2; i < a; i++) {
    if (a % i === 0) {
      return myFunction(++a);
    }
  }

  return a;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.